# Pointer to ViewController lost on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app fails on my iPhone 7, which is running iOS 10. However, it runs fine in the simulator and an old (32 bit) iPad running iOS 9. The problem seems to be that the change to 64-bit pointers is making an array used to set things up is too big for the stack.

I've tried increasing the stack size, using the setrlimit function, but the stack size is already maxed out on the device, and I don't have the authority to increase the "hard limit".  So, I must place this array on the heap. However, ARC balks at my use of pointers involved with malloc.

```
Node** nodePointerArray = malloc(sizeof(Node*) * MAX_COLUMNS * MAX_ROWS);
```

If someone could please point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thanks.

### Github repo

[Xcode project](https://github.com/56phil/LC-Project.git)

Comment: I think you should provide crashlog.

Comment: I'm simply getting a null pointer exception. No stack trace, registers, anything else. If there is a crash log, I would be happy to provide it. Where should I look for it? Thanks.

Comment: Use this instruction https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/retrieving-crash-reports-on-ios and load crashlogs from your iPhone 7 device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that needed to be done was to use linker flags (-Wl,-stack_size,200000) to increase the size of the stack.